# Validate url with array paramter in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to add `preg_match` validation for a URL like:

`http://test.com/page/?param1[0=a&param2[1]=b`

If you see in above example one square bracket is missing.

Comment: We really need to know some of the possible variations in the URL, otherwise you could just escape the special characters and use exactly the URL as the regex.

Comment: Do you think it will suffice to check if the string has an unbalanced number of `[`s and `]`s? E.g. `if (!preg_match('/^[^\[\]]*+(\[(?>[^\[\]]|(?1))*+\][^\[\]]*+)++$/', $url) { return false; }`?

Comment: @Reshma: If you think my approach works for you, please let me know so that I could post it as an answer.

Comment: It is working only for given example param1[0=a&param2[1]=b. This is not required that only above array structure will come to in validation. Url could be anything valid link. But i wanted to add validation if there are array parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking with two regex, may this works for you

```
$website = 'http://test.com/page/?param1[0=a&param2[1]=b';

if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website) || !preg_match("/^[^\[\]]*+(\[(?>[^\[\]]|(?1))*+\][^\[\]]*+)*$/",$website)) {
    echo "Invalid URL"; 
}else{
    echo 'valid';
}
```

O/p: Invalid URL

The only problem with this check is It only check bracket unbalance, not its position.

Comment: Yes its seems working fine. I need to check with using seperator '& ' on top of that. Thanks for the answering.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need a regular expression for this. You could simply use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which will do the parsing and validation for you, and then you can check that each component is as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried with parse_url along with all parse functions like parse_str, for further checking component. But its not giving fulfilment of my requirements